# Вывод старшего интегрального типа в шаблоне

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Посоветуйте решение вот такой проблемы. В шаблоне нужно получить тип наибольшего размера для данного интегрального типа. Например, для `uint*_t` это будет `uint64_t`, для `int*_t` - `int64_t`, и т.д. То есть объявление выглядит примерно так:

```
template<typename T>
class Value {
  public:
    using R = ?????;

    R get();

  private:
    T val;
};
```

и специализация `Value<int16_t>` должна развернуться в

```
class Value {
  public:
    int64_t get();

  private:
    int16_t val;
};
```

В функциях шаблонов ничего подходящего не нашел. Есть здесь хорошее простое решение или уже не морочить себе голову и пойти другим путем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть просто сделать вот так?

```
using R = std::conditional_t<std::is_signed_v<T>, std::int64_t, std::uint64_t>;
```

Comment: Есть же еще `char*_t`, и кстати, еще ведь `float/double` нужно, забыл про них. Но как вариант можно из этого что-нибудь намутить.

Comment: @freim формально, точных типов а-ля `uint64_t` может вообще не быть (они опциональны по стандарту), поэтому надо использовать `uint_least64_t`. Пока 128 не завезут, конечно.

Comment: @älёxölüt Вообще да, но это скорее экзотика. Можно еще взять `[u]intmat_x`, раз автор хочет *"тип наибольшего размера"*.

Comment: Кстати, да. Что-то я `max` не приметил сразу. Ну и `std::` не хватает, как [недавно выяснилось](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53744128/3240681).

Comment: @älёxölüt, я неточно выразился. `uint64_t` меня вполне устроит в качестве старшего типа. Какой-то неопределенный "наибольший" не нужен.

Comment: Скажу честно, ответ меня не устроил, потому что для набора `signed/unsigned/char/float/bool` который мне нужен, он приводит к совершенно безумным конструкциям. Но насколько я понимаю, нормального решения тут не существует, так что хоть какой-то ответ... В результате не стал с шаблонами связываться, проще получилось расписать это обычной иерархией классов с можественным наследованием.

Comment: @freim Сами же написали в вопросе, что тип интегральный. Какой вопрос - такой и ответ. :) Если хотите, сделайте новый вопрос и распишите требования точнее, может что-нибудь сможем подсказать.

Comment: Интегральные типы - это `signed/unsigned/char/bool`. Выкидывание типов с плавающей точкой ситуацию не сильно упрощает. Но я это писал без всякой претензии - ваше решение подходит, если надо сделать обязательно с шаблонами. Но мне, к счастью, не обязательно.